# How to overwrite :path_names for custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've implemented RESTFUL routes in english but the application is for german users so the routes should be renamed to german. I did this using the :path_names option and for the CRUD routes but this doesnt work for the routes I created on my own. For example the model `SingleBudget` has an action that removes specific objects from a n..n association. In my `routes.rb`it looks like this:

```
resources :single_budgets, :path => 'einzelbudgets', :path_names => { :new => 'neu', :edit => 'aendern', :remove => 'entfernen' } do
     collection do
          get ':id/remove' => "single_budgets#remove", :as => :remove
     end
end
```

It works for the new and edit action but not for the remove action. Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:path_names` parameter will only affect the built-in CRUD actions. For your custom actions, just call it what you want right in the `get` parameter:

```
get ':id/entfernen' => "single_budgets#remove", :as => :remove
```

This will give you a `remove_single_budgets` path that will point to `/single_budgets/:id/entfernen`, which will execute the `remove` method in your controller.